# Meaning of 嗜み（たしなみ）

Tags: meaning, words

I've run into the expression 嗜み quite often lately, mostly in the form of "XXXの嗜み", like 大人の嗜み or メイドの嗜み

Googling around, I think I understand that it means something along the lines of "what you should know as XXX", but I'm not quite sure I get all the nuances of the word.

Could someone explain to me the scope of 嗜み and in what situation I might use the word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

嗜み means two different things:

1. hobby; enjoyment as an amateur
2. what you should know to be a refined X; basic knowledge/experience for X

So 大人の嗜み can refer to either:

- hobbies only adults can enjoy (e.g., wine and cigarette. See [this article](https://gakumado.mynavi.jp/freshers/articles/47871) for example)
- what you should know/have as a mature adult (See [this article](https://stylestore.jp/note/detail/3054) for example)

メイドの嗜み almost certainly refers to "what you should be able to do as a maid" because "hobby (only) for maids" doesn't make much sense to me.

The verb version, 嗜む, also means two things, "to casually enjoy something as a hobby" and "to have the basic knowledge/experience on something".

嗜む/嗜み is an elegant word that is typically used with uncommon "upper-class" activities like 乗馬, テニス, チェス, ピアノ and 生け花. Saying アニメを嗜む is not wrong but may sound a little funny.

Comment: finny って？　-----

Comment: @Chocolate 「魚のヒレ状」だそうです。…なおしましたすみません